# How to link parent with child?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

when I try to create a gift card for an order, the card is saved but it is never linked to its parent.
I looked so many resources but none of them helped me understand the cause .

Here's my Order.rb :

```
Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :order_items, dependent: :nullify
  attr_accessible :billing_address_id, :shipping_address_id, :shipping_address, :billing_address, :email, :shipping_address_attributes, :billing_address_attributes, :bill_to_shipping_address
  before_save :update_subtotal
  before_save :populate_guid
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :giftcard, dependent: :nullify
  belongs_to :billing_address, :class_name => "Address"
  belongs_to :shipping_address, :class_name => "Address"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipping_address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address, reject_if: :bill_to_shipping_address
  validates_uniqueness_of :guid
```

my Giftcard.rb

```
class Giftcard < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :from, :to, :message, :img1, :img2, :img3, :img4, :choose, :order_id
  belongs_to :order
end
```

routes :

```
resources :orders, only: [:new, :create, :update] do
    resources :giftcards, except: [:index, :show]
end
```

orders/new.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to new_order_giftcard_path(@order), data: { modal: true } do %>
    go
<% end %>
```

giftcards/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@order, @giftcard], remote: request.xhr?, html: { data: { modal: true } } do |f| %> 
  From<%= f.text_field :from, placeholder: "Martin" %>
  To<%= f.text_field :to, placeholder: "Jeanne" %>
  <%= f.text_area :message, placeholder: "Thanks" %>
  <%= f.submit "go" %>
<% end %>
```

and finally my giftcards_controller.rb :

```
class GiftcardsController < ApplicationController
respond_to :html, :json
layout false, :only => [:edit, :new, :show]
before_action :set_giftcard, :only => [:create, :update]

def new
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    @giftcard = Giftcard.new
end 

def create 
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    @giftcard = Giftcard.new(gift_card_params)
    if @giftcard.save 
       @order.update(params[:order])
       @giftcard.update_attribute(:choose, true)
       respond_modal_with @order, location: new_order_path
    end
end 
private

def gift_card_params
    params.require(:giftcard).permit(:from, :to, :message, :img1, :img2, :img3, :img4, :order_id)
end
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Controller

```
@order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
@giftcard = @order.build_giftcard(gift_card_params)
```

Comment: please up answer..if it is helpful